# In-app purchase introductory price sandbox test fails

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am developing a new feature for our app and I'm having a few problems to test introductory prices. I'll describe the configuration I'm testing.
I created two products to test introductory prices. The first one is set to be used as 2 months with a reduced price and after that regular price. The second one is set to provide the first month for free and regular price after that.
Both products were created in the same way but changing the payment mode (pay as you go for the first and free trial for the second)
When I test free trial subscription with a fresh sandbox account it works as expected. However when I try to purchase "pay as you go" product with a new fresh sandbox account it shows the message "You are all set -  Your purchase was successful" but immediately after dismissing the alert control an error appears with description:

```
SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

Product is fetched correctly and I can access to discount information. So I assume product has been created correctly. Also I validated the receipt and purchase is not reflected.

Am I missing something? All tests are being performed in real device, not simulator. How can I test the IAP before sending the version for submission?

Comment: This seems to be related to a widespread issue in Sandbox right now: https://twitter.com/RevenueCat/status/1106235357413036032

Comment: Seems everything is working normally today :)